# bar chart not coinciding with axes in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart in d3.js and unfortunately, the bars are not on the axes. They are appearing somewhere else. Can you please point out what I am doing wrong here.

I think it has do with the placing of axes and all but I am unable to figure it out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="rer"></div>

    <script>
        var width = 400, height = 400;
        var data1 = { 2011: 9, 2012: 12, 2013: 10, 2014: 8, 2015: 12, 2016: 20 }
        data_ready = d3.entries(data1);
        var barColor = '#50740a';
        var svg = d3.select("#rer")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var xscale = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data_ready.map((function (d) { return d.key; })))
            .range([0, width - 100]);

        var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data_ready, function (d) { return d.value; })])
            .range([height / 2, 0]);

        var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale);

        var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100, 20)")
            .call(y_axis);

        var xAxisTranslate = height / 2 + 10;

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100, " + xAxisTranslate + ")")
            .call(x_axis);

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data_ready)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr("x", function (d) { return xscale(d.key); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return yscale(d.value); })
            .attr("width", xscale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yscale(d.value); })
            .attr("fill", barColor)





    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You add the axes to a g that is translated, try adding the bars to a g that is translated the same amount. Remember to account for the translate in the scale ranges: you won't be using full width and height as the range. There [is a common form](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention) for margins with d3, this will help with placement as you are hard coding values for axis margins, which complicates placement and scale ranges.

Comment: great thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to correct it and got the graph as below. Can someone please explain the attr ( transform, translate ) thing. This seems to be the issue. I did a trial and error method to place the position of the graph. Is there a better way to do this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="rer"></div>

  <script>
    var width = 400,
      height = 400;
    var data1 = {
      2011: 9,
      2012: 12,
      2013: 10,
      2014: 8,
      2015: 12,
      2016: 20
    }
    data_ready = d3.entries(data1);
    var barColor = '#50740a';
    var svg = d3.select("#rer")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var xscale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data_ready.map((function(d) {
        return d.key;
      })))
      .range([0, width - 100])
      .padding(0.1);

    var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data_ready, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })])
      .range([height / 2, 0]);

    var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale);

    var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(100, 10)")
      .call(y_axis);

    var xAxisTranslate = height / 2 + 10;

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(100, " + xAxisTranslate + ")")
      .call(x_axis);

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xscale(d.key);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yscale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("width", xscale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height / 2 - yscale(d.value);
      })
      .attr("fill", barColor)
      .attr("transform", "translate(100, 10)")
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```